# Modern calendar view: how to hide the events pane by default?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Probably a simple thing that I am just overlooking.

I have a SharePoint list with a calendar view. When the calendar view is opened, the right pane showing the day's events also opens. I want to have that right pane closed by default, and only open when the Events Pane item (top right) is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no SharePoint out of the box settings available to hide the events pane by default in calendar view.

So, you have to hide the events pane manually using this icon:

[image]

Comment: Pity, thank you anyways.